# Convert pandas nested Series into Numpy ndarray

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
Category  Subcategory  Count
A         1            [20.0 38.5, 3.2 8.5]
A         2            [3.7 8.2, 5.7 5.5]
A         3            [12.4 23.5, 24.4 8.9]
B         1            [3.7 8.2, 5.7 5.5]
B         2            [12.4 23.5, 24.4 8.9]
...      ...           ...
...      ...           ...
```

Column `Count` contains Strings that I would like ultimately to convert to `Numpy ndarray`.
In the end, my goal is to create an ndarray **for each `Subcategory`** **per `Category`**.
What I tried is to group the df by `Category` and iterate over each group, get the String of `Count`, strip the `[]` and split it at the space character and use these with the `np.to_numpy()` to create the ndarrays, but it doesn't seem to work as desired.

For example for `Category A` and `Subcategory 1` I would like something like this:

```
[
[20.0, 38.5],
[3.2, 8.5]
]
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

-- So far this is a working but not efficient approach:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby('Category')
for group_name, df_group in df_grouped:
    f = df_group.Count.str.strip("[]")
    for items, values in f.items():
        List = []
        s = values.split(",")
        for i in s:
            vals = i.strip(" ").split(" ")
            val1 = float(vals[0])
            val2 = float(vals[1])
            List.append([val1, val2])
```

Comment: Why a 4 elements `Count` column to a 2x2 ndarray? Is it always so? And how your trial not worked as desired?

Comment: Actually it is not always 2x2. It is a 2-d array in terms of splitting for each row to `,` character and then in `space` character. My naive approach was to loop over each df row, strip the `[]` and split into comma, but then I have to iterate the new list to split in space and append each value in the array but this has to be done for 1.2mil lines, so I was wondering how can this be done somehow more efficiently.

Comment: Consider using `ast.literal_eval` to make actual lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it should strip the brackets and create the double array:

```
def reshape_array_string(x):
    temp = x.replace('[', '').replace(']','').replace(',','').split(" ")
    shapelen = len(temp)//2
    return (np.reshape(temp, [shapelen,2])) 

df['Count'].apply(reshape_array_string)
```

output:

```
0              [[20.0, 38.5], [3.2, 8.5]]
1    [[3.7, 8.2], [5.7, 5.5], [4.6, 2.2]]
```

Comment: This is very close to being correct but the extra `,` in the second array values mess things up.

Comment: @Omen try my latest update, i fixed that. I think this is what you wanted, i added a third string, since you said it could be more than two pairs

Comment: I believe this is correct. I will give it a try in the full dataset and let you know if there any efficiency issues. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thx, let me know, i'm interested, that's a large dataset.